# JMeter Test doesn't load completely

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I have a problem with my load test on JMeter. I set:

Number of Threads = 10
Ramp-Up-Period = 1
Loop Count = 1

So normally the Test goes up to the 10 Threads (10/10) (You can find this in the right upper corner!) and then goes back to zero. My Problem is, that my JMeter Test just goes up to (4/10) and then back to zero. I have no idea why it doesn't work normally.

I tried this with another Number of Threads, e.g. with 20. And the problem also occurs in that example. The test goes up to (7/20) and then back to zero. But it should go up to (20/20).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please add details on your testing setup to your question. Also, refer to  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 1):

Your test is setup for `loopcount=1` and your threads start up gradually. Do you think your first thread will still be active by the time the last thread starts up?

For your particular test, apparently there are at-most 4 active threads at some point of the test execution. If your test runs for a very short time, if the first thread exits before second thread starts, you wont even get that, the max you'll see is `1/10`

If you need all threads to be active at the same time, either

- Increase the length of your transaction beyond ramp up time
- Have a larger loop count so the threads are active longer
- Reduce or eliminate your ramp-up time so all threads become active simultaneously (Though this is usually a bad idea)